# numpy.in1d return incorrect bool values

Tags: python, numpy

I try to find continuous elements in a 1d array. However,it doesn't seem work in the following case, anyone knows why, or I did something wrong?

```
In [21]: a
Out[21]: array([ 0. ,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9])

In [22]: b
Out[22]: array([ 0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8])

In [23]: c
Out[23]: array([ 0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4])

In [24]: a[np.in1d(a, b)]

Out[24]: array([ 0.5])
```

I expect output is the same as b, but it only returns first value

```
In [25]: a[np.in1d(a, c)]
Out[25]: array([ 0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4])
```

However, in this case, it works. I am confusing?

Comment: Take a look at `repr(a[6])` and `repr(b[1])`.  You'll see that they are not exactly the same (e.g. one might be something like `0.59999999999999998` while the other is `0.60000000000000009`).

Comment: Compare: `exacteq = (a[5:9]-b)==0` and `close = abs(a[5:9]-b)<0.000001`. These should each be boolean arrays and will illustrate the problem with floats that Warren explained.

Comment: @user38776 it works for me on NumPy 1.9.0, Python 2.7.8, Windows 7 (all 64 bit)

Comment: @SaulloCastro: Whether or not it works will depend on how `a` and `b` are created.  I can reproduce the result with `a = np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)` and `b = np.arange(0.5, 0.9, 0.1)`.  On the other hand, it will work if `b = a[5:-1]`, because then the values in `b` are actually exactly the same values in `a` (they are both views of the same memory).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser but in my case it works with both arrays having independent memory allocations. The only case I can reproduce the OP's problem is using `np.float64` for `a` and `np.float32` for `b`

Comment: @SaulloCastro, it's the well-known problem of comparing floating point values for equality.  I'm sure if you tried other ways of generating `a` and `b`, you would run into a case where it would fail.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I'm aware of this, I just thought it helpful to report this case worked on my system...